# How to call CreateProcessW in ahk?

Tags: winapi, autohotkey

I want to call the windows function CreateProcessW in ahk with DllCall.

In the helping file of ahk in the DllCall function it does not talk about how to fill the structures with a pointer,and it's required in the [security attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa379560(v=vs.85)) struct.

I tried omitting the params with this code `DllCall("CreateProcessW", "WStr", "notepad.exe")` but it does nothing.

Comment: The security attributes struct is not required.

Comment: https://documentation.help/AHK_H-2.0/Run.htm

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can [Creating a new Security Descriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/creating-a-security-descriptor-for-a-new-object-in-c--) or as [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) said, set `NULL` which means the handle cannot be inherited and gets a default security descriptor.